# Get full URL from a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, url

I am trying to find URL form a sting. I want to check if string contain any URL.

For that sake i wrote code :

```
function get_url_from_string(str) {
        var searchText = str,
          urls = searchText.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig);
         for (var i = 0, il = urls.length; i < il; i++) {
            var ur=urls[i];
        }
        return ur;

    }
```

But it returning only URL with out any parameter. For Example if i pass:

> Hi Check This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHOc-4D7MjY

It gives me https://www.youtube.com Only

I want to get full url.
I have no idea of regular expression.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Try [`\b(?:https?)?(:\/\/)?\S*\.\w{2,4}[^\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/jT5sC3/1)

Comment: It is showing error.

Comment: This `\.(\w{2,4}` says match a `.` then 2-4 characters of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So your expression ends at the `.com`. Adding `\S*` after the `\w{2,4}` would allow it to continue until it hit a whitespace. https://regex101.com/r/rI1nN4/1

Comment: I have done it my self  `\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b.(\S*) ` :) Thanks For your help.

Comment: You also can simplify the `(http|https)?` into `(https?)?

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
/\b(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?\s/
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This** it works well for me.

```
      var url_regex = /(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?/gi;
      var text = "some text string here!!";
      var urls_array = [];
      while ((urls = url_regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
                            urls_array.push(urls[0]);
                    }
```

> This code is used in my project

Answer (score 2):

```js
function get_url_from_string(str) {
 
        var searchText = str,
          urls = searchText.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})?(.*)\b/ig);
         for (var i = 0, il = urls.length; i < il; i++) {
            var ur=urls[i];
        }
  alert(ur);
  
        return ur;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="x" onclick="get_url_from_string('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHOc-4D7MjY')">click here
</button>
```